# Adjust sensitivity of trackball in Linux Mint 13

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I am using Logitech Trackball Marble and I have difficulty adjusting the sensitivity of it in Linux Mint 13.

Apparently the sensitivity and acceleration setting in Linux Mint only work for the mouse. ( I have both mouse and trackball plugged)

How can I adjust it? I searched about it in google but find no useful result. I've seen people digging in something called xorf.conf but I have no idea what it is. I check my /etc/X11 directory and found no xorf.conf but only some file looks like xorf.conf.fail

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the graphical settings interface simply can't support more than one pointing device. Therefore, you may need to add the device and adjust its settings in **xorg.conf**. Check out the documentation on how to do that here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB

Once you've defined the device, it looks like you can use xorg.conf's "Sensitivity" option to adjust it, or use `xinput`:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/135122/reduce-the-mouse-sensitivity

They don't specifically go into it on that answer, but `man xinput` shows that `[DEVICE]` can be one of the primary arguments to xinput.

**Update**

In your question, you say you have both a mouse and trackball plugged in. In your bounty comment, you say you need a solution because you only use a trackball. If you unplug the mouse and only plug in the trackball, then Mint's graphical Mouse configuration in the Settings panel should work just fine to configure the trackball sensitivity. (Where it gets tricky is defining what your trackball buttons do-- emulating scrollwheel and middle click behavior, if necessary, but that's not what you asked about...)

Comment: It only applies to Ubuntu and I am using Linux Mint. The configuration and environment setting is different. There is no guarantee of success. It could screw up my keyboard configuration.

Comment: Linux Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu, so *most* directions for Ubuntu work for Mint, unless they are Unity-specific. (I say this as a user of both Ubuntu and Mint.) `xinput` changes the X configuration, which does apply to Mint.

Comment: First there is no 50-marblemouse.conf in the xorg.conf.d directory of my Mint 13 xfce. Secondly, the sensitivity doesn't work for trackball even if I unplugged the mouse.

Comment: 50-marblemouse.conf will not exist until you create it.